# Mozilla Firefox memory leak 56.0.2 64-bit

Tags: windows-10, firefox, memory, 64-bit

I noticed that after a few days on my PC Windows 10 64-bit Mozilla Firefox 56.0.2 64-bit starts to use a lot of RAM - it could reach 2 GB or so, and browser operation becomes slower. Only restarting the browser fix this. Also this problem persists on older Firefox versions, and on different operating systems (Win XP for example). How to solve this problem?

Comment: Remove all extensions then verify if the problem still exists

Comment: try Firefox 57 (beta)

Comment: Yes, I will try both.